# Dynamic height increase of one div with respect another div

Tags: css, html

I have two divs. These two divs are orientated as two vertical columns next to each other. Instead of pre-determining the height of the divs via css I want to have it grow dynamically with the content I put into it. Which is simple enough for one div but my problem is that I want the div on the left with background color green to grow to the same height of the div on the right . There is always going to be more content in the right than in left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the elements are after `body`. Give 100% to the body, and all the div

```css
body, #div1, #div2 { height: 100%; }
```

If they are not, then you have to either fix the height of the parent or chain `100%` height all the way to the body again.

```css
#parent { height: 800px; }
#div1,#div2 { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose those divs in a parent div, and set their height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a three-column (X)HTML + CSS Layout.

It's [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Let insert a parent div (container of those two adjacent divs)
2. add a property 'display: flex;' to the parent div

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
}

.child1, .child2{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">
            CHILD 1 AREA<br />
            CHILD 1 AREA
        </div>
         <div class="child2">
             CHILD 2 AREA
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```